# Как через API проверить открытость комментариев в сообществе?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Не могу найти метод или параметр в методе, позволяющий узнать открыты ли комментарии в группе/паблике или нет. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прямого метода в API нет, но немного обходным путём можно это сделать: достать, к примеру, последнюю (в смысле самую свежую) запись на стене данной группы (например через  метод **[wall.get](https://vk.com/dev/wall.get)**) и у ответа в объекте `comments` проверить поле `can_post` на 0 или 1. **[can_post](https://vk.com/dev/objects/group)** — информация о том, может ли текущий пользователь оставлять записи на стене сообщества.

Быстрый пример через запрос **[execute](https://vk.com/dev/execute)**:

```
return API.wall.get({owner_id:-1}).items[0].comments.can_post; // вернет 0
// return API.wall.get({owner_id:-10502438}).items[0].comments.can_post; // вернет 1
```